# How to manage fragment lifecyle in tab in android?

Tags: android

I have an app which contain three tab with three fragment mainly `A,B,C` lets suppose I am on tab 2 which contain fragment `B` when app goes in background and again resume then fragment `A` is showing instead of fragment `B`. Ho do I resolve that?

Comment: What do you mean by goes in background ? How you make the app to go in background ?

Comment: You could try saving  the tab position in the SavedInstanceState and restore in onCreate